How to make a dynamic sequence in kotlin
I am processing huge amounts of xml documents and am wondering how to dynamically flush a sequence to disc when the memory footprint is to large.
The ByteArray of the xmls will vary huge. Sometimes I cannot run more than 2 documents before running out of memory, but most times it takes hundres of document.
Is it possible to accomplish the following without using for/while-loops?
val listOfDocumentIds: List<Long> = ...

listOfDocumentIds
   .asSequence()
   // ... read documents until limit of xml memory footprint are reached
   // ... process read documents
   // ... write processed documents to disc
   // ... loop back to where reading halted and continue reading/processing



Why don't you just write one processed document at a time to disk?

How are you currently processing multiple documents in parallel? How do you calculate the "xml memory footprint" of a document?

Frankly speaking, if you sometimes can't handle even 3 at once, then it sounds dangerously close to not being able to process even a single one.

If I am not mistaken, Channels are basically designed to handle issues like yours so I would suggest taking a look at its docs

the purpose of processing as many before saving to disc is better performance and to avoid the huge number of files produced

channels look interesting, but a quick overview of https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html seems to kill the "dynamic" part. when a send is closed, how do I report back to the sender that x docs are not processed? it is really good that this can be done async, but the sender needs to know what is written to disc and what docs need to be processed once more

The answer is yes - except I don't know how you'd know when your memory limit is about to be reached.
fun processXmlDocs(listOfDocumentIds: List<Long>): Sequence<XmlDoc> = sequence {
    listOfDocumentIds.forEach { docId ->
        val doc = XmlDoc() // do some processing here
        yield(doc)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val listOfDocumentIds: List<Long> = listOf(1,2,3)
    val xmlDocsToPersist = mutableListOf<XmlDoc>() // this is the memory buffer
    processXmlDocs(listOfDocumentIds).forEach { xmlDoc ->
        xmlDocsToPersist.add(xmlDoc)
        if( MEMORY_GETTING_FULL ) {
            persistAll(xmlDocsToPersist)
            xmlDocsToPersist.clear()
        }
    }
    // drain down the last chunk
    persistAll(xmlDocsToPersist)
}

class XmlDoc {}

Yes, this has a for loop, which I am sure you can simplify further, but like the above it conveys how to use Sequences alongside a forEach which is considered a terminal operation - such operations actually cause the sequence to produce data.

this is basically what I am doing. I check if a ByteArray reaches a limit, then persists all and clears the processed documents.

I would like a code with better readability (like the comments above) so I can avoid the extra call to persistAll in order to save the last chunk
